# Kiwi TCMS junit.xml-plugin export fails with error 'version' not found

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I'm setting up this plugin to export test results to Kiwi tcms (test case management system) in a github actions pipeline.

I can get the plugin to log in and interact with our Kiwi instance. I can see that the account is authenticated and other values are updated (product-version).

I don't know how to provide the 'version' value that it needs.

This is how I have the plugin configured in git actions.

```
      - name: Install kiwitcms plugin and create config
        run: |
          pip install git+https://github.com/kiwitcms/junit.xml-plugin@v12.2.999
          cat > ~/.tcms.conf << _EOF
          [tcms]
          url = https://app.com/xml-rpc/
          username = foo
          password = bar
          _EOF
        shell: bash

      - name: Run kiwitcms export
        run: tcms-junit.xml-plugin $([ "false" == "true" ] && echo "-v") --summary-template '${classname}.${name}' ./app/build/reports/*.xml
        shell: bash
        env:
            TCMS_PREFIX: "Android App 2022"
            TCMS_PLAN_ID: "8"
            #        TCMS_PARENT_PLAN - if defined newly created TestPlan will be a child of this one
            #        TCMS_RUN_ID - if defined will report results to this TestRun
            TCMS_PRODUCT: "App Android"
            TCMS_PRODUCT_VERSION: "1.4"
            TCMS_BUILD: ${{ github.sha }}
```

I get this error on the "Run kiwitcms export' step:

```
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault -32603: "Internal error: Cannot resolve keyword 'version' into field. Choices are: bug, build_run, id, is_active, name, product, product_id, testexecution">
```